# What did happened with the 2 in equation (3.82) to (3.83)?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, geodesics

[image]

I have tried to do the same computing by the definition of the Christoffel symbols by the metric and the result is the same that the image, but i don understand what occur with the number 2. Why did it dropped?

Comment: $A_{\mu\nu} x^\mu x^\nu = A_{00} x^0 x^0 + A_{ij} x^i x^j + A_{0i} x^0 x^i + A_{i0} x^i x^0$. If $A$ is symmetric, then $A_{\mu\nu} x^\mu x^\nu = A_{00} x^0 x^0 + A_{ij} x^i x^j + \textbf{2} A_{0i} x^0 x^i$.

Comment: Thanks so much @Prahar . I hadn't realized that.  :)